# Can I tell if my app is running under Apple Test Flight Beta

Tags: testflight

In the prior test flight system we pushed AdHoc builds which we used a compiler constant to identify to turn on/off features for our beta testers.  Now with Apple's Beta Test Flight System we have to build for the App Store, i.e. not AdHoc, which is fine as if it tests good we can use the same build for a production review.

Is there any way from within iOS to detect that the build is a Test Flight delivered build so we know "this is beta" and do the same as before with the AdHoc compiler constant?

Thank you

Comment: Check out these answers:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12431994/detect-testflight

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27297435/detect-if-ios-app-is-downloaded-from-apples-testflight

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to tell at runtime whether an iOS app is running through a TestFlight Beta install](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26081543/how-to-tell-at-runtime-whether-an-ios-app-is-running-through-a-testflight-beta-i)

Comment: This looks promising: https://twitter.com/tapbot_paul/status/557551769496997888

Answer (score 2):

There is one way that I use it for my projects.

In Xcode, go to the the project settings (project, not target) and add "beta" configuration to the list:

[image]

Then you need to create new scheme that will run project in "beta" configuration. To create scheme go here:

[image]

Name this scheme whatever you want. The you should edit settings for this scheme. To do this, tap here:

[image]

Select Archive tab where you can select `Build configuration`

[image]

Then you need to add a key `Config` with value `$(CONFIGURATION)` the projects info property list like this:

[image]

Then its just the matter what you need in code to do something specific to beta build:

```
let config = Bundle.main.object(forInfoDictionaryKey: "Config") as! String
if config == "Debug" {
  // app running in debug configuration
}
else if config == "Release" {
  // app running in release configuration
}
else if config == "Beta" {
  // app running in beta configuration
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple and useful function you can use in any app to easily check if the running app was installed by TestFlight:

```
func isTestFlight() -> Bool {
    guard let path = Bundle.main.appStoreReceiptURL?.path else {
        return false
    }
    return path.contains("sandboxReceipt")
}
```

No need to create special build configs, schemes, etc.

Comment: Looks like it doesn't work anymore since iOS13 unfortunately

Comment: Yes, it's not working. @imike did you find any solution?

Comment: @Thinesh I tried a lot but haven't found any solution unfortunately :(