# Can an iOS app "know" if it's a beta distribution through Apple's Testflight?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, testflight, xcode-scheme

I'm in the middle of transitioning from TestFlight's native app to Apple's TestFlight through iTunes Connect. My Xcode Project is set up with a beta scheme and a distribution scheme, so I can include a number of debug features in the beta version using a custom flag (lots of `#ifndef PROD` in the debug code). The beta scheme also has a separate bundle identifier and bundle display name, so that beta and distribution can live side by side on a tester's phone (separate icons, etc).

With Apple's TestFlight, the bundle ID needs to be the same for beta and for distribution. Because of that, I can't include any of the debug features in my current arrangement.

I'm looking for a way around this. One possibility I thought of was to create another app in iTunes Connect solely for testing, but that seems dirty. Is there a conditional or a way to test, in the code, whether the current build is a TestFlight build or a distribution build? Or is there a better way to handle this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why not use a test-flight only scheme that has a Flags build setting?

Comment: @matt: He is asking about iTunes Connect beta testing. There is nothing to do with new schemes. You need to upload the build with distribution profile for beta testing.

Comment: Maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27297435/detect-if-ios-app-is-downloaded-from-apples-testflight

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to tell at runtime whether an iOS app is running through a TestFlight Beta install](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26081543/how-to-tell-at-runtime-whether-an-ios-app-is-running-through-a-testflight-beta-i)