# iTunesMetadata.plist location on ios8

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8, app-store

I want to identify if the current version of an app using my SDK was downloaded from the AppStore, till now I used this code:

`[[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:[NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"iTunesMetadata.plist"]]`

Since ios8 I get false even if the version is from the AppStore.

Do you know where did the file move to? Any other mechanism you propose?

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps you:

In iOS8, the application bundle has been moved. According to @silyevsk, the plist is now one level above [the new application main bundle path], at /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/4A74359F-E6CD-44C9-925D-AC82E‌‌​​B5EA837/iTunesMetadata.plist, and unfortunately, this can't be accessed from the app (permission denied)

Please refer here for more details: [How can I detect if the currently running app was installed from the app store?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18282326/how-can-i-detect-if-the-currently-running-app-was-installed-from-the-app-store)