# How I can check If the app is bought from appstore?

Tags: ios, xcode, licensing

I want to check if my app has been bought from the appstore to send a value to my Database, to have a statistical data.

I have been reading from the developer guide of apple, but I didn't found anything.

Someone has info about that?

EDIT: the post [How can I detect if the currently running app was installed from the app store?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18282326/how-can-i-detect-if-the-currently-running-app-was-installed-from-the-app-store) didn't solve my problem. The propossed check in the post is deprecated.

Comment: And what is your other option than the App Store? HockeyApp, TestFlight

Comment: I don't have any other options, I'm a noob in this aspect. What I can do to check this inside my app, and send the result to my server?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I detect if the currently running app was installed from the app store?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18282326/how-can-i-detect-if-the-currently-running-app-was-installed-from-the-app-store)

Comment: That's my point, there is no other official way to distribute apps than the App Store. If you need to differentiate the production (App Store) and the testing version of the app, then that can be solved with `#if` directives.

Comment: @Sujania in that post the people says after iOS 8, these method is not available. Bojan Dimovski I don't want to diffrerentiate the production, I only want to have a list of user that paid the app (I have a login access in my app), to differentiate the free and the paid user.

Comment: So, if you distribute a free and a paid version of the app, then you'll have two separate targets in Xcode and two items in iTunes Connect. If you want to distribute a single free app and extend it to a full version using In-App Purchases, then you'll have to change the user info when that payment is done or restored.

Comment: The apps are different, they are two separate projects. :(

Comment: If the only difference is the subset of features for the paid app, than you should consider having one project with two targets. If they are completely different apps with separate code and you can put different database flags for the paid and the free app, then I am not sure that I see the problem :)