# How to determine if request is from the application downloaded from app store

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, networking, client-server

I have a client - server application. Client (iOS application) has to download content from the server. Is it possible to determine if request is from the application downloaded from the App Store of just regular request (should be dropped)? Is exists a possibility to avoid hardcoded credentials in the application?
Thanks

Comment: Checkout this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18619270/1463604

Comment: My question is a bit different. I need to check on Server Side if request comes from the legal application. Not just determine inside the application.

Comment: Well, you will have to add a 'environment' parameter in your request from client side. Afterall, the server will know only if the application tells it somehow (via request in your case)

Comment: My intention is to check some UID (or whatever generated in valid app) within the appstore.